# Best way to find nested opening and closing tags

Tags: ruby

I am making a basic discussion board using ROR. When a user posts a response to a message, the input textarea is prepopulated with the message in quotes using a tag: **[QUOTE]**. As such the format is:

> [QUOTE]quoted message goes here[/QUOTE]

Currently, I have a simple solution that replaces [QUOTE] and [/QUOTE] with HTML using *message.sub('[QUOTE]', 'html goes here')* as long as [QUOTE] or [/QUOTE] still exist. When I go to respond to a quoted message, I convert the HTML back into the [QUOTE] tag to ensure that the prepopulated input textarea doesn't have HTML in it. As such, a quote of a quote, will look like:

> [QUOTE][QUOTE]quoted message here[/QUOTE][/QUOTE]

Here is the problem. If I run my current method again, I will get duplicated HTML fields like:

```
<div class='test'><div class='test'>quoted message goes here</div></div>
```

Instead, I want to be able to have a solution that looks like:

```
<div class='test1'><div class='test2'>quoted message goes here</div></div>
```

And so on...
Any suggestions on the best way to loop this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do depth tracking you'll have to use the block method for `gsub`:

```
text = "[QUOTE][QUOTE]quoted message here[/QUOTE][/QUOTE]"

quote_level = 0

new_text = text.gsub(/\[\/?QUOTE\]/) do |m|
  case (m)
  when '[QUOTE]'
    quote_level += 1
    "<div class='test#{quote_level}'>"
  when '[/QUOTE]'
    quote_level -= 1
    "</div>"
  end
end

puts new_text.inspect
# => "<div class='test1'><div class='test2'>quoted message here</div></div>"
```

You could make this more robust when handling invalid nesting pairs, but for well-formatted tags this should work.

Comment: This looks perfect! Since you mentioned it, I'm curious how you would approach invalid nesting pairs using this solution?

Comment: You're going to have to ensure that `quote_level` doesn't go below zero at any point, meaning you've closed too many, and that at the end of your conversion it is exactly `0` as otherwise you'd have unclosed tags.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea:

Take this regex

```
(\[QUOTE\])(.*?)(\[\/QUOTE\])
```

And apply it to your string. It'll match opening tag, closing tag and content. Then take the content and apply regex again. If there are any matches, that'll be your second level of nesting. Repeat while have matches.

Demo here: http://rubular.com/r/MkGsnUj3vL

Comment: I checked your example and I think it only works by coincidence. If you alter it slightly it will use the `.*` greedy matcher and leave you with an unmatched `...[/QUOTE][QUOTE]...` pair in the middle. `.*?` is generally the safer way to go about matching even if it isn't very good at catching nested pairs.

Comment: I think you should update your regex to `(\[QUOTE\])(?!\[QUOTE\])(.*?)(\[\/QUOTE\])`. Note the added negative lookahead. This way you're not matching two open `[QUOTE]`s to a single close `[/QUOTE]`. (the first match returned)

Comment: @Luke is there any way to get the original expression to ALSO match the second `[/QUOTE]` tag?