# regex to exclude intermediate opening and closing tags

Tags: ruby, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular Expression to match outer brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets)

Is there a regex that will return:

```
[aaaa[aaa]aaaa]
```

from

```
aaa"fields":[aaaa[aaa]aaaa]aaa
```

This is in the context of getting an array from a JSON string that also contains XPaths.  The XPaths have opening and closing square braces just like the array, hence the generalised problem of retriving a string delimited by opening and closing braces that it also contains as substrings... I hope that makes sense.

I think you need to keep track of the number of opened pairs of square braces and only when it has reached 0 do you return that portion of the string.  This would require a loop but I was wondering if there a pure regexp solution.

My first attempt was:

```
cleaned_defintion = defintion.gsub(/\[\d*\]/,"")
```

which transforms XPaths such as this: `html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/div[7]/div[2]/input[1]` to `html/body/form/div/div/input` but this will leave xpaths with elements like:

```
td[@width='113']
```

which then breaks:

```
json_fields = cleaned_defintion.match(/fields":(\[[^\]]*\])/)
```

This question has an answer that uses the iterating approach:
[Best way to find nested opening and closing tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402005/best-way-to-find-nested-opening-and-closing-tags)

Comment: have you tried matching the braces "greedily"?

Comment: @Kash yes, but I wasn't sure how to pair the braces?  Also please bear in mind there may be more opening and closing sets proceeding the pair desired.

Comment: @acheong87 thanks the links to the other questions, I couldn't seem to them before.